# Doesn't understand "Cannot convert floating-point register value to non-floating-point type."

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I've got the following method in a C++ program:

```
const f3Vector Rasterizer :: calcBary(const f2Vector &va, const f2Vector &vb, const f2Vector &vc, int x, int y){
float alpha, beta, gamma;

gamma = ((va.y-vb.y) * x + (vb.x-va.x) * y + va.x * vb.y - vb.x * va.y) /
        ((va.y-vb.y) * vc.x + (vb.x - va.x) * vc.y + va.x * vb.y - vb.x * va.y);

beta = ((va.y-vc.y) * x + (vc.x-va.x) * y + va.x * vc.y - vc.x * va.y) /
       ((va.y-vc.y) * vb.x + (vc.x - va.x) * vb.y + va.x * vc.y - vc.x * va.y);

alpha = 1 - beta - gamma;


return f3Vector(alpha, beta, gamma);
}
```

whereas `f2Vector` is a typedef for a `t2Vector<float>` and a `t2Vector` is a Vector whose elements consist of an x- and y-value. When I execute this in the debugger, I get the message:

> Cannot convert floating-point register value to non-floating-point type.

for the calculation of `gamma` and `beta`. The specific input parameters were

> va.x = 274.0276 | va.y = 249.23909
>
> vb.x = 282.0854 | vb.y = 332.82899
>
> vc.x = 161.1564 | vc.y = 311.15881

What does this message from the debugger mean, and how should I rewrite my could, so that the issue does no longer exist?

**EDIT**

The method `calcBary()` is called by the following function

```
void Rasterizer :: rasterTriangle(const f2Vector &va, const f2Vector &vb, const f2Vector &vc) {
// compute Bbox
int x_min = int(floor(fmin(va.x, fmin(vb.x, vc.x))));
int y_min = int(floor(fmin(va.y, fmin(vb.y, vc.y))));
int x_max = int(ceil(fmax(va.x, fmax(vb.x, vc.x))));
int y_max = int(ceil(fmax(va.y, fmax(vb.y, vc.y))));


// clipping
if(doClip){
    if(x_max > clipWidth){
        x_max = clipWidth - 1;
    }
    if(y_max > clipHeight){
        y_max = clipHeight - 1;
    }
}



// loop over every pixle in the Bbox
for(int x = x_min; x <= x_max; x++){
    for(int y = y_min; y <= y_max; y++){
        const f3Vector v = calcBary(va, vb, vc, x, y);
        if(0 <= v.x && v.x <= 1 && 0 <= v.y && v.y <= 1 && 0 <= v.z && v.z <= 1 ){
            shader->shadeTrianglePixel(x, y, v);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: @VaughnCato Uhm, not sure which information you need exactly. I'm using Qt Creater (on Ubuntu 12.10), is that sufficient already?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was interested in.  I've never seen that error though.  Can you provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @VaughnCato Take the values for va, vb and vc as mentioned in my post and for x = y = -2147483648 (I got these numbers reproducing the error, and it makes me think, that this could be the actual problem :-))

Comment: You've only posted a small section of a larger piece of code, so I can't actually go through the same steps that you are.

Comment: @VaughnCato I've added the function calling `calcBary()` - does this suffice?

Comment: It may or may not suffice to someone who has infinite amount of time on their hand and/or infinite desire to help. For the rest of us, SSCCE